# How to get the Badge render instant after clicking from another route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

**This is my first post so be gentle if i wasn't specific enough or made stupid mistake**

So i am building a shop for my semester project in ReactJS(basic Reactjs: no redux or any database), and if it is important i just started to learn about JS and REACT.

I"m using AntDesign UI and controlling the routes through react-router-dom, [this is my file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD5uQ.png) just for the understanding.

I have statefull component that return a cart icon with badge and this component is called from the Header.

lets say i"m inside the landingpage component which located in the folder src->landingpage, and each press on a specific button there should be increment the badge by 1.

now the problem is that i can see the badge increment only after clicking   and not in "real time" on the header, how do i make it work in real time through any component?

Cart(badge).js code->

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Icon, Col, Badge, Button, Switch } from 'antd';
import CartCount from '../CartCount'
const ButtonGroup = Button.Group;
class Cart extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            count: 0,
            show: true,
        }
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        var counter1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Carts"))
        if (counter1 != this.state.count) {
            this.setState({ count: counter1 })
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        var counter1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Carts"))
        if (counter1 != this.state.count) {
            this.setState({ count: counter1 })
        }
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <Col offset={23}>
                <Badge count={this.state.count}>
                    <span style={{ fontSize: "50px" }} className="head-example"><Icon type="shopping-cart" /></span>
                </Badge>
            </Col>
        )
    }
}

export default Cart;
```

Header(contain badge inside).js code->

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

    import { Layout } from 'antd';

import Login from '../login/login'
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'
import Cart from '../CartIndex/Cart/Cart'
import { Row, Col, Button, Tabs, Icon } from 'antd';
import './Header.css'

class Header extends Component {
state=({
count: 0,
reload: false
})
  render() {

    const { Header } = Layout;

    return (
      <div>
        {/*Login section*/}
        <Row>
          <Col span={24}>
            <Login />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        {/*Header section*/}
        <Row>
          <Header style={{ fontFamily: 'Anton', fontSize: "50px" }}>
            <Col span="23">
              <a style={{ color: "white" }} href="/">Store</a>
            </Col>
           <Link to="/CartIndex"><Cart/></Link> 
          </Header>
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Header)
```

the onClickHandler function im doing in the landingpage->

```
onCartHandler = () => {

if (localStorage.getItem("Carts")) {
    var counter1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Carts"))
    counter1 += 1;
    localStorage.setItem("Carts", counter1)
}
else {

    var Counter = JSON.stringify(1)
    localStorage.setItem("Carts", Counter)

}
message.success('Successfully added to cart')
}
```

I hope you guys can resolve and make me understand what i did wrong or didn't even knew from the first place, i researched about all the lifecycle components but it was to generic for me to understand without see code examples.

Thanks a-lot and have a great day in the office

Comment: You have to modify the state to force a re-render of the component. You are just storing the counter in `localStorage`. Read up on React JS states.

Comment: yeah, i understand i just having hard time to open my head because as far as understand i call the increment  function from another unrelated component and i catch the change with componentDidUpdate() which lead to setState (and that should render the component in real time(?)) so i"m not just storing the the localstorage.... i"m pushing it into the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You badge counter is bound to your component state in Cart(badge).js.
This is where it's interesting to understand component lifecycle, i know it can be hard to understand but here is an article about it : https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-react-v16-4-new-component-lifecycle-methods-fa7b224efd7d
What is happening is a click on the badge launchs the componentDidUpdate function from your component lifecycle, this is why it get updated from searching in your local storage. There is not direct data binding between your local storage and this.state.count from your component, this is all made with your component lifecycle.

Now to correct this there is multiple solutions, one way or another you need to update your component state, or use some other mechanic than state, for example a Redux Store ( yeah this is more to learn again ).

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, i will try read it again and again until i fully understand it.
I will try also to learn about Redux because i knew i would encounter problems without using it...